# NewRelic no data reporting from docker mule 3.8.0

Tags: docker, mule, newrelic, mule-esb, newrelic-platform

I added this configuration in wrapper.conf in mule and I run a docker script that up mule, and it works:

```
wrapper.java.additional.4=-javaagent:/opt/newrelic/newrelic.jar
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Dnewrelic.config.app_name=mule
```

But if I remove that configuration from wrapper.conf and I start the mule container with this script:

```
    JAVA_OPTS="-javaagent:/opt/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Dnewrelic.config.app_name=mule_container"

docker run -d --name mule_container -e NEWRELIC_HOME=/opt/newrelic -e CONTAINER_NAME=mule_container -e JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS" mule_image
```

It fails and I don´t see anything in newRelic. NewRelic say "No data reporting for this application "

Do you know why? I would like to have all the newRelic configuration in the docker script. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_OPTS is an environment variable used by Tomcat and perhaps other Java applications to pass Java arguments. Mule ignores it so that would explain why only setting the properties in wrapper.conf works.